i cant open camera file
I got a camera not too long ago, and when I connect it to my computer, all I get is this file. (I use a USB cord I bought off amazon). sI don't know how to screenshot, so apologies for lack of screenshot.
The folder name is "90C0-9205" and the file name is "100MSDCF". ive tried opening the file with every app on this computer but all they say is "input/output error". when i look at the folder and file properties, it says "inode/x-corrupted type". does this mean the file is corrupted? if so, is it salvagable? again, im sorry for the lack of knowledge, i am just trying to look at the pictures on my camera. its a sony cybershot dsc- p9. i also got this computer from my sisters teacher. its an old hp and it runs on linux/ubuntu? i dont know which one but its one of those or both i think. please ask me for more information on this if needed, ill cooperate and help as much as i can. thank you!

Ubuntu is one of the flavors of Linux

try the same thing with a windows computer

The 100MSDCF file is probably an image file (probably a JPEG).   What happens if you double-click on it?   Do you have image-viewing software?   Can you try to open the file manually with the image-viewing software??

Any camera will give a suffix to a file: .JPG for images, .MOV for movies, etc. Google 100MSCDF -- it is the Sony default name for a directory, not a file. Click on it to open it. Did you format the storage device in the camera options -- a Linux format is probable not compatible with the camera? Personally, I don't use USB: I remove the SD card from the camera and put in into my laptop, which auto-mounts it, and runs its default image reader/printer/saver app.

sorry for the late response, but it opens image viewer and says "Failed to open file '/media/user/90C0-9205/100MSDCF': Input/output error".
